# Country code flag icon is not showing on form in for loop

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, django

I am trying to getting flag icon on every edit form of each datatable row have edit button. but unfortunately I can see flag icon only in 1st row of edit form of datatable grid. and in other rows I am not able to see flag icon. Can you help us how can I modified my javascript so I can see flag icon on every edit form of each row of datatable.

NOTE : We have code is in Django Python and the variable is in DTL (djnango Template Language)

See below screenshot for understanding

Image -1 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dWOW.png) (Datatable screenshot)
Image -2 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn4a5.png) (if I click on 1st row of datatable then I can get flags in fields)
Image-3 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryhsO.png) (If I click on second row of datatable then I have not get flags icon in field.)

{% for vr in adduser.adduser.all %}




{% csrf_token %}

Edit Contact Data

×

```
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="FirstName">First Name<span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname"
                    placeholder="Type FirstName here...." value="{{vr.f_name}}" required />
                  <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="LastName">Last Name<span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" id="lastname"
                    placeholder="Type LastName here...." value="{{vr.l_name}}" required />
                </div>
                <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="Address">Address Line1<span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addln1" id="addln1"
                    placeholder="Type Address here...." value="{{vr.add_ln1}}" required />
                  <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="Address">Address Line2</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addln2" id="addln2"
                    placeholder="Type Address here...." value="{{vr.add_ln2}}" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-row">

                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <label for="Country">City<span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="city" placeholder="Type city here...."
                    required value="{{vr.city}}" />
                  <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <label for="Country">Country<span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="country" id="country"
                    placeholder="Type Country here...." value="{{vr.country}}" required />
                  <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
                </div>



                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <label for="Country">Zip Code<span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Type zipcode here...."
                    value="{{vr.zip}}" required />
                </div>
                <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
              </div>



              <div class="form-row">

                <div class="form-group col-md-6 smsForm_edit">
                  <label for="contact1">SMS No.<span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label>
                  <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="smsno_edit" id="smsno_edit" value="{{vr.sms_no}}"
                    placeholder="SMS No." pattern="^(00|\+)[1-9]{1}([0-9][\s]*){9,16}$" required />
                  <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter valid contact no.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 whatsappForm_edit">
                  <label for="contact2">WhatsApp No.<span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="whtspno_edit" id="whtspno_edit" value="{{vr.whtsp_no}}"
                    placeholder="WhatsApp No." pattern="^(00|\+)[1-9]{1}([0-9][\s]*){9,16}$" required />
                  <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter valid contact no.</div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <script>
                
               
              const phoneInputField_edit = document.querySelector("#smsno_edit");
              const phoneInputField2_edit = document.querySelector("#whtspno_edit");
              const phoneInput_edit = window.intlTelInput(phoneInputField_edit, {});
              const phoneInput2_edit = window.intlTelInput(phoneInputField2_edit, {});
          
              $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.smsForm_edit .iti__flag-container').click(function () {
                  var countryCode = $('.smsForm_edit .iti__selected-flag').attr('title');
                  var countryCode = countryCode.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                  $('#smsno_edit').val("");
                  $('#smsno_edit').val("+" + countryCode + $('#smsno_edit').val());
                });
                $('.whatsappForm_edit .iti__flag-container').click(function () {
                  var countryCode = $('.whatsappForm_edit .iti__selected-flag').attr('title');
                  var countryCode = countryCode.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                  $('#whtspno_edit').val("");
                  $('#whtspno_edit').val("+" + countryCode + $('#whtspno_edit').val());
                });
              });
             </script>

              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="email">Email<span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Type email here...."
                    value="{{vr.e_mail}}" pattern="[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+" required />
                  <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter valid email address.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="Department">Department Name<span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label>

                  <select class="form-control" name="deptnm" id="deptnm" required readonly>
                    <option>{{vr.dept_nm}}</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label>Broadcast list<span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label>

                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="brdctlst" name="brdctlst" value="{{adduser.brl_name}}"
                    readonly>
                  
                  </select>
                  <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--Form End-->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
                Close
              </button>
              <button href="{% url 'broadcastlist' %}" id="UpdateUser" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
            </div>
          </form>
          <div class="alert alert-info" style="display: none;"></div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}


    <!--Edit Model End From Here-->
```

Comment: Welcome, could you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: I have added screenshot for your understanding. I hope that will help you.

Comment: Type MCVE is not assignable to type screenshot

Comment: Also [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: so this is what that I can share with you for now, Thanks

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: I mean to say I can share only this code as I mention in this question.

Comment: Idk man just create a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io) it would save time to us all

Comment: Hi , I have added snippet code for your reference.